# How to make the entrypoint run a start service script without exiting container in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  xx:
    image: xx:1.0
    container_name: instance
    command: /home/admin/start.sh start && tail -f /dev/null
    network_mode: "host"
    tty: true
```

I use `docker-compose up` to start the container.

The problem is the container will show `Exited (0)` after the `start.sh start` finished.

I know command or entrypoint will launch a `pid 1` process, if the process was finished, the container would  exit.

So, I add the `tail -f /dev/null` to prevent it from exiting, but I can't figure out why it still exit.

I just want start the service(`/home/admin/start.sh start`) and keep the container alive. What the `command` should be in the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1):

You should run the application *as a foreground process*.  Do not use a "service" script or anything else that launches the application as a daemon.

```yaml
# Run the application itself, not a "start" script that launches
# a background process
command: /home/admin/admin_application
```

Typically this main command is a property of the image: whenever you start the container this is the thing you'll almost always want to run.  That means it's more appropriate to specify this as the `CMD` in your Dockerfile:

```sh
CMD ["/home/admin/admin_application"]
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` you don't need to override this value.  You also shouldn't usually need to specify `container_name:` (Compose can assign this on its own), `tty:` (only needed for interactive programs), or `network_mode: host` (which generally disables Docker networking).  Your `docker-compose.yml` can be as little as

```yaml
version: "3.9" # "3" means "3.0"
services:
  xx:
    image: xx:1.0
    # ports: ["8080:8080"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is there any temporary way to fix the command problem, if I don't want to build the image again.